# Is it possible to compile twice and build separate packages only by writing debian/rules?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, dpkg

Let me elaborate my question with some further details on what I attempt to accomplish.

My end-goal is to have two debian packages: one which contains binaries built for x86 and the other for ARM. In the debian/control I have two different packages defined and Architecture is currently set to “any” for both the packages.

I attempted to follow the instructions on https://wiki.debian.org/PkgSplit and also looking at the rules.multi2 example for debhelper (http://www.fifi.org/doc/debhelper/examples/rules.multi2), but so far without any luck.

The source is a Qt-project which is to be deployed both for x86 and ARM.

I’m successfully building with dpkg-buildpackage, but no matter how I try my source code is only compiled once.

What would be the ideal way to reach my goal, is it “simply” enough to enter the correct information in debian/rules for this to work, or do I have to take another approach? I’m not really sure if this is possible at all; that I have simply got the wrong road to begin with (I’m new to the world of debian packaging).

(I’m deliberately not including my debian/control and debian/rules at this stage, if needed I’ll provide with further details since they are a bit messy at this stage).

Edit:
I was lead to the PkgSplit by this comment https://askubuntu.com/questions/246718/change-environment-variables-in-debian-rules-according-to-debian-control-targets/908351#908351
But for me the answer is a bit cryptic so a helping hand would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no.

a single run of `dpkg-buildpackage` will create binary packages for a single architecture (either `amd64`, or `i386`, or `armhf` or `s390x` or whatever).

just call `dpkg-buildpackage` multiple times to (cross)build for multiple architectures:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot --host-arch i386
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot --host-arch armhf
```

this will create (at most) 3 packages: one of the native architecture (most likely: `amd64`), one for `x86_32` (aka `i386`) and one for the raspberry (`armhf`).

btw, the *PkgSplit* docs talk about creating multiple packages for the same architecture. e.g. when you have a library, you usually want to split that into the library part (installing `libfoo.so.1`) and the development part (installing header files).

Comment: That settles it then, thanks for the information how it should be achieved. _PkgSplit_ it lead me on the wrong path, thanks for clarifying it!